# Matplotlib Save color from cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

Been unable to figure this one out so was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction...

I am basically trying to store the color that was used from my colormap such that I can use it later on in the code.

```
color_map = cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
for grp,frame in x.groupby('time'):
   ax.scatter(x, y, cmap=color_map)
       <other code>
   ax.axvline(x=magic_number, color=<???>)
plt.show()
```

Pretty much I want to use the same color from my map in the for loop. I believe this is pretty simple to do but I cant seem to find the right combination of things to search for to get the answer.

Comment: Does your scatter plot have different colors or all dots are the same color?

Comment: The scatter has different color dots since I am plotting on the same ax and showing it afterwards.

Comment: So you can scale each of your dot in the range between zero and one. If so color will be color_map(your_scale). You can call color_map, it is a function of one argument - float between 0 and 1. It returns which returns a tuple of RGBA

Comment: The code that is shown will not produce differently colored scatter dots and the definition of the colormap will be ignored. It would be nice to show a [mcve] such that it is clear what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, that may not have been precise enough. You will of course get differently colored scatter points, but their color will have nothing to do with the colormap you define. Because of that it is still unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: What I don't understand is: your dataframe is named `x`, you're iterating over it's groups created by `time` - but within the loop  you are plotting `x` over and over again ? But the variables which change, i.e. `group` and `frame` are not used at all... But some strange `y`, which is not defined anywhere is used - but this obviously doesn't change while looping again. Can you explain that, please?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't completely understand what you are trying to achieve. I'm not sure that below will be helpful.... (sadly)

your code should be something like this:

```
ax.axvline(x=magic_number, color=color_map(float(magic_number)/float(max_magix_number) ) )
```

It works quite simple `float(magic_number)/float(max_magix_number)` gives a float number in the range from zero to one. `color_map(scaled number)` returns required color as a tuple of R,G,B and transparancy....

```
>>> c = get_cmap('Spectral')
>>> c(0.5)
(0.998077662437524, 0.9992310649750096, 0.7460207612456747, 1.0)
>>>
```